Fit canvas to Image - Grease Pencil
There's a way to fit the entire canvas in the image?

I want to export a character animation, but the output is including the entire canvas as expected. How to rezise the canvas to fit in that area?
Also, when creating a new 2D Animation, is visible the canvas as a "paper" in the background. While resizing the Output->Format->Resolution, the canvas still visible, but then after rotating the 3D Viewport, this canvas just disappears, forever. How to bring it back or avoid this behaviour?
PS: Any tip to create characters with Grease Pencil and exporting to Unity will be very usefull.
Thank you in advance!

The thing you call "Canvas" is the portion of the 3D world that the Rendering Camera sees, according to its location, rotation and Focal lenght.
So, to resize the rendered drawing you have two options:

select the Grease Pencil object, go to edit mode, select all and use G,R, S to Grab, Rotate and Scale the whole drawing as desired.

Enable the Camera Collection in the Outliner (top right window), select the camera, use G, R to move the camera and frame the drawing correctly (use G, Z, Z to Dolly in and out).


Be aware that by default AutoRecording option is enabled when using 2D Animation preset, so moving the camera will get keyframes on it if you don't disable it in the timeline window (red circle button on transport).
When orbiting in the 3D world the Camera view gets disable (of course), to restore it press Numpad 0 (or Menu > View > Viewpoint > Camera), or press the little camera icon on top right of the 3D view.
The "canvas" proportions, as they are properties of the rendering camera, vary according to the output resolution that you set in the Output properties.


Hi. Thank you for answering, but the question is about resizing the canvas, which is not a term I invented. There's even a tab with that name right next to the 2D Animation tab, so I guess there's a way to work with that.
I don't want to change my grease pencil, and I would like to avoid messing around with the camera as well, if possible. I understand that the camera is the way to render, but considering there's a feature called Canvas, I guess there's a way to fit it in the image.
Also, after rotating the viewport, I don't want to lose that "paper" reference of the canvas.

Canvas is not a feature of Blender (nor of any 3D application), it's only the name of a UI configuration. The name of that fetaure is Passepartout, which is nothing but lowering the brightness of areas outside the Camera view: as I said the only parameters you can set are about the camera (move, rotate, focal lenght). There are many ways in which you can move the camera (and its Passepartout). Maybe try pressing N, go to View tab and enable the "Lock Camera to view" function.
